# Hibernate @Generated annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 3.3.4 with Hibernate 5.1.3, with java 1.7, and Sql Server DB. I wrote a simple class mapped to a Table and it works, but I ran into problem when I added an autogenerated field using annotation `@Generated`. My expectation was that upon insert into DB the field value would be generated by DB, but instead I get an exception that says that null value may not be inserted into this field. (In DB it is non-nullable field). Here is fragment from my class with the definition of the field:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Date createDate;
```

And here is the exception:

```
    Hibernate: insert into harvesting_task (task_size, priority, request_data, task_name, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-12-18 15:28:48.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 515, SQLState: 23000
2016-12-18 15:28:48.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_date', table 'webadmin.dbo.harvesting_task'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
2016-12-18 15:28:48.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.cyberbit.common.model.HarvestingTaskImpl entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
2016-12-18 15:28:48.637 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [null id in com.cyberbit.common.model.HarvestingTaskImpl entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)]
2016-12-18 15:28:48.638 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by commit exception
com.cyberbit.common.exceptions.EntityRetrievalFailureDueToInfrastructureException: Error occurred while saving task to DB
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:25) ~[HarvestTaskManagementRepository.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementService.java:45) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$82836951.invoke(<generated>) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3b058eb.submitTask(<generated>) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementController.java:44) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3424) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:23) ~[HarvestTaskManagementRepository.class:?]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_date', table 'webadmin.dbo.harvesting_task'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3424) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:23) ~[HarvestTaskManagementRepository.class:?]
    ... 52 more
2016-12-18 15:28:49.826 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController - An error has occurred
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.cyberbit.common.model.HarvestingTaskImpl entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:542)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:286)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3b058eb.submitTask(<generated>)
    at com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate configuration is fine. The problem was the Table definition in the DB. In order for everything to work the column that supposed to be auto-generated needs to to be defined with default value. I.e. after DB table is created the following command needs to be executed:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[task] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_task_created_date]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created_date]
GO
```

This should be done for any field that is supposed to be auto-generated. This is not obvious and is not mentioned in Hibernate documentation (at least for version 5.1) more so that even if you write your own annotation using `@ValueGenerationType` meta-annotation and write your annotation as shown in [Hibernate documentation 5.1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated) to use DB generation it still won't work unless column is altered to have default value.

Comment: Pretty rare information, hard to find anywhere else. Thank you for sharing.